# NodeJS export multiple classes from different scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, export

Let's say I have:
**script1.js**

```
class A{
   constructor(){
      this.name = A
   }
}
```

**script2.js**

```
class B {
   constructor(){
      this.name = B
   }
}
```

then I have **clients.js**

```
const clientA = require('./script1');
const clientB = require('./script2');
module.exports = {
   clientA : clientA,
   clientB : clientB
}
```

And finally **index.js**

```
const clients = require('./clients/Clients.js');
const clientA = new clients.clientA();
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: clients.clientA is not a constructor

I'm kinda new in javascript, do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: How have you exported the `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to `require` A and B you need to export them first: something like `module.exports = A` in your script1.js and the same for B

Comment: Yes. that's right. something like this. 
```
module.exports = class A{
  constructor(){
     this.name = A
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not exporting anything in "script1","script2".

```
module.exports = class A{
   constructor(){ 
       this.name = A   
}}
```

and

```
module.exports = class B {
   constructor(){
       this.name = B
   }}
```